# For loop doesn't increment indexes properly

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I'd like to store input from keypad in array, but my for loop doesn't seem to work properly. Instead of reading an input from keypad, adding it to the array, and then incrementing the index, the program keep printing weird indexes.

**Code**

```
    void loop(){
  char arr[3];

  for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
      char input = customKeypad.getKey();
      if (input != NO_KEY){
        do{
             arr[i] = input;
             Serial.println("Index");
             Serial.println(i);
             Serial.println("Value");
             Serial.println(arr[i]);
          } while(input == NO_KEY);
      }
  }
}
```

**Console output**

```
Index
2
Value
1
Index
1
Value
2
Index
1
Value
3
Index
1
Value
4
Index
2
Value
5
Index
2
Value
6
```

Comment: `input` never gets updated so the while loop will run forever. Try adding `input = customKeypad.getKey();` into the loop so it keeps checking the key.

Comment: More to the point, closing that `do` loop is `} while(input == NO_KEY);` . *Look at your code*. Where is it *ever* possible that condition can change, and therefore break the loop, if `input` is ever `NO_KEY` going into that do-while ?

Comment: this is the fourth question you ask about the same problem. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/89646/cant-get-input-from-4x4-keyboard

Comment: Are you clearing the previous key click state?

Comment: Make toyr life easier and print text and value in ***single*** line `Serial.print("Index: ");
             Serial.println(i);`

Answer (score 0):

This is the dataflow of your program. This probably could be a comment but I needed the visualization to make it more understandable. It is not really clear what you want to do:

[image]

For instance, if you enter, in this order:

```
input==NO_KEY
input!=NO_KEY
input!=NO_KEY
```

You update the indexes #1 and #2, then the iteration (arduino loop) restarts and you can overwrite the values of the array. Is this what you want?

Also notice that the while loop never gets repeated, this is very clear from the dataflow.

I have rewritten you program to be tested outside of Arduino:

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define NO_KEY 'a'

int main(){
    while(1){

      char arr[3];

      for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
          char input;
          printf("%d -> ", i);
          scanf(" %c",&input);
          if (input != NO_KEY){
            do{
                 arr[i] = input;
              } while(input == NO_KEY );
          }

      }
      for (int i = 0; i <3; i++){   printf("Value %d\n",arr[i]); }

      printf("\n Reset\n");
    }
}
```

And this is the output, as expected from your code

```
0 -> a
1 -> b
2 -> c
Value 127
Value 98
Value 99

 Reset
0 -> b
1 -> a
2 -> a
Value 98
Value 98
Value 99
```

Comment: it is artuino - scanf or printf

Comment: "I have rewritten you program to be tested outside of Arduino:"